# Prevent login user to web application if already login Struts 2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

How can I prevent a user to log in, if that user is already logged-in on a different system using Struts2 framework?

Comment: I edited you post (grammar) and I changed it assuming you were referring, to the same user being logged in somewhere else. If that is not the case (prevent log in when anybody is logged in somewhere else) please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: May be you need to manage it using database.

Comment: If user directly close the browser instance, who i can reset that in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are able to integrate [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt) with you existing application than there is simple configuration to handle it by just adding few line into configuration.

Add the following line into you configuration file

```
  <http>
    ...
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
  </http>
```

It will allowed only one user login at time, if user is login from different system or browser it will give message that user is reach maximum login limit.

[Reference Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/spring-security-example-tutorial-how-to.html).

If you spring security is not an option than you may use below option.

> Use a SessionInterceptor which will check for session validity, if
>   session is valid it will check if user is already logged in to the
>   application (for this you will have to maintain session somewhere for
>   eg database for every successful login), if valid login is found,
>   redirect user again to login page with custom message, or logout
>   already valid session and then redirect him to login again. If you
>   logout earlier session it would mean any successive action in that
>   browser session will have to deal with invalid session.